# Self-Implementation of Gradient Descent Compared to SciPy Minimize

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

This is an assignment for a convex optimization class that I'm taking. The assignment is as follows:

> Implement the gradient descent algorithm with backtracking line search to find the optimal step size. Your implementation will be compared to Python's [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function.
>
> The specific function to minimize is the least squares function. The error between the solution found by the Python library and your implementation must be smaller than 0.001.

I've made an implementation but the error value hovers around 1, and have been searching for ways to improve it but have been having some trouble. Here's the code that I wrote:

**Gradient Descent + Backtracking Line Search Implementation**

```
import numpy as np

# Gradient descent.
def min_gd(fun, x0, grad, args=()):
    alpha = 0.3
    beta = 0.8

    delta_x = -grad(x0, *args)
    t = backtracking_line_search(fun, x0, grad, delta_x, alpha, beta, args)
    x_new = x0 + (t * delta_x)

    if np.linalg.norm(x_new) ** 2 > np.linalg.norm(x0) ** 2:
        return min_gd(fun, x_new, grad, args)
    else:
        return x_new
    
# Line search function returns optimal step size.
def backtracking_line_search(fun, x, grad, delta_x, alpha, beta, args=()):
    t = 1
    derprod = grad(x, *args) @ delta_x

    while fun((x + (t * delta_x)), *args) > fun(x, *args) + (alpha * t * derprod):
        t *= beta

    return t
```

**Other given functions**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import gd

# Least Squares function
def LeastSquares(x, A, b):
    return np.linalg.norm(A @ x - b) ** 2

# gradient  
def grad_LeastSquares(x, A, b):
    return 2 * ((A.T @ A) @ x - A.T @ b)
```

The error between the two results is basically calculated using the L2-norm.

Some ideas that I've came up with are that the tolerance checking point in my gradient descent function may be flawed. Right now I'm essentially checking simply whether the next step is larger than the previous. However, I'm also having trouble wrapping my head around how I might improve that.

Any feedback is appreciated.

**Edit**

In case anyone is curious on the final code that I wrote to make it work in the desired way:

```
def min_gd(fun, x0, grad, args=()):
    alpha = 0.3
    beta = 0.8

    delta_x = -grad(x0, *args)
    t = backtracking_line_search(fun, x0, grad, delta_x, alpha, beta, args)
    x_new = x0 + (t * delta_x)
    
    if np.linalg.norm(grad(x_new, *args)) < 0.01:
        return x_new
    else:
        return min_gd(fun, x_new, grad, args)
```

I simply fixed the conditional statement so that I'm not just comparing norms, but also checking if the value is smaller than a predetermined tolerance level.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: You should be trying to implement the strong Wolfe conditions. Here is a good resource.
http://terminus.sdsu.edu/SDSU/Math693a/Lectures/06/index.php?subdir=06_Lecture&page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess about the tolerance checking is right: the norm of the current vector is not related to convergence. A typical criterion would be a small gradient, so `min_gd` should look like

```
def min_gd(fun, x0, grad, args=()):
    alpha = 0.3
    beta = 0.8
    eps = 0.001

    x_new = x0
    delta_x = -grad(x0, *args)
    while np.linalg.norm(delta_x) > eps:
        t = backtracking_line_search(fun, x_new, grad, delta_x, alpha, beta, args)
        x_new = x_new + (t * delta_x)
        delta_x = -grad(x_new, *args)

    return x_new
```

where `eps` is some small positive tolerance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It helped out a lot. If it's not too much trouble, could you please elaborate on what you mean by "the norm of the current vector is not related to convergence?" Do you mean that the norm I'm checking right now is basically not sufficient enough to check for convergence? Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to this check: `np.linalg.norm(x_new) ** 2 > np.linalg.norm(x0) ** 2` in the original `min_gd` which continues the search as long as the norm increases. This is not related to convergence: the negation, a decreasing or constant norm does not necessarily imply that the search has converged.